# How to set default response headers for jpeg images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, response-headers

Ok so I have read a little about mod_headers however I have seen no definintive code to put in htaccess or anywhere else as for what to use in order to add the default response headers of Last-modified and Content-length to my jpeg images that other webites grab from me. Without these they cant check whether or not to download the entire image again or not. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Content-Length" is set automatically. At first remove "Last-Modified" and append a new one. Works only in .htaccess if allowed.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header append Last-Modified "Fri, 01 Mar 2012 12:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Another option is to adapt a caching interval.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    # on access
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # or on modification
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "modification plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I would prefer the caching on access combined with "Last-Modified".

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header append Last-Modified "Fri, 01 Mar 2012 12:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Why do you override Last-Modified?  This serves no useful purpose.  For static files this is automatically set from the files last modified DTS.

Comment: Content-Length does not appear on the VPS I am using? I do not know why and really need it as it is beyond my control what headers this other website I am working with needs to receive. It is also not cacheing that I require it is whether or not the other site should download the image.. if the length and last-modified are different chances are the file is different. Also you write in "Fri, 01 Mar 2012 12:00:00 GMT" statically does this change dynamically?

Comment: Ignore the bit about the Content-length.. after adding the last-modified stuff it nows shows up.. although the last modified is set to the date show is there a way to make this the actual last modified date of the file?

Comment: @TerryE you are right but on some machines the Last-Modified by default behaves strange like showing date of creation and not modification, so it could be an option to send a custom header. If I see it right, the Last-Modified is only send for first call, not for revalidation.

Comment: @Ash if you only use the expires section and leave out the Last-Modified part, it should normally send Last-Modified with the default date from file-system and Content-Length. As I wrote in comment to TerryE, this behaves strange on some machines, I would use the expires date for revalidation and caching issues.